# Как удалить совпадения в паре массивов Python?

Tags: python, массивы, сортировка

Есть два массива:

```
a = [10, 17, 14, 19]
b = [10, 18, 16]
```

Мне нужно оставить только уникальные элементы, в этом случае:

```
a = [17, 14, 19]
b = [18, 16]
```

Как это лучше реализовать на Python?

Comment: что делать если одно число в одно списке более одного раза, а в другом ни одного? важен ли порядок?

Comment: Порядок не важен, числа в списке не повторяются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a1 = list(set(a) - set(b))
b1 = list(set(b) - set(a))
```

Comment: спасибо большое)